# What does “drunch” mean?

Tags: word-usage, neologisms

Macmillan  Dictionary gives two definitions of ***[drunch](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/drunch)*** which derive from the combination of two different sets of words:

> 1 - a meal that combines lunch and dinner.
>
> - *Let's eat early and have drunch this afternoon.*
>
> 2 - a drink plus lunch.
>
> - *In Barcelona there are some places offering an all you can eat drunch buffet including a drink such as bloody mary, cava or gin tonic.*

while  the following source appears to support the idea that  ***[drunch](https://neologisms.rice.edu/index.php?a=term&d=1&t=21366)*** is more a combination of drinking and having lunch  rather than a meal that combines lunch and dinner together, along the lines of the more established term ***[brunch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brunch)***:

> ***Drunch is a blend of the words “drinking” and “lunch.*** ” It is primarily used as a noun in place of the word “lunch.” An example is “Let’s get drunch.”  It means to get drinks at lunch. However, the meaning has shifted over time. Drunch can now mean: to consume excessive quantities of alcohol at lunch, or to get drunk at lunch. An example of this usage would be: “We got so drunch, yesterday.” This definition often leads to a folk etymology, where people see the word as a blend of “drunk” and “lunch.”

(neologisms.rice.edu)

Given that the two definitions are quite different and inviting someone  to drunch may sound as inviting them to a round of drinks, I’d like to know:

- Is there an established usage of drunch in one the two senses explained above or should it be used carefully to avoid possible  unpleasant misunderstandings?
- when and by whom was the term coined? Was it from one of the realities such as Masterchef, for instance?

Comment: OK, so there are 3 possible interpretations 1. a very late lunch, around 2-3pm  2. a very early dinner 4-6pm or 3. a drink just before lunch. I don't think reality TV shows such as Masterchef has any relevance. This appears to be business jargon.

Comment: I'm not making this an answer as I've done no research, but anecdotally as a native (British) English speaker I've never heard this term - my immediate interpretation was the second meaning (i.e. combining lunch with drinking). The first would never have occurred to me, and frankly seems odd even after seeing it defined (where did the 'r' come from? It's not in lunch or dinner - interference with 'brunch' is my best guess). If you mean that, I'd either explain very clearly or (preferably, imo) avoid the term entirely.

Comment: @Mari-LouA- so, “let’s get drunch” that is “let’s get drunk at lunch” is business jargon.   Any evidence? Why should realities about cooking  not  be responsible for this term?

Comment: Dinner/lunch would surely be _dunch_ – or, as I have always called it, [***lunner***](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lunner) (also more parallel to _brunch_, which is the first part of the earlier meal and the last part of the later meal). I’ve never heard _drunch_ either, and devoid of context (as when reading the title of this question), I assumed it to be a verb similar in meaning to _drench_, _dunk_, or _drown_.

Comment: Also, I’d question the last bit of that Neologisms quote. It’s not a folk etymology when people think of _drunch_ as being ‘drunk + lunch’ both in composition and meaning – it’s just a new word, made up of _drunk_ and _lunch_ and meaning ‘to get drunk at lunch’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I can assure you that the term exists and is  used, at least among chefs. The reasearch I presented appears to suggest a more common usage is spreading.

Comment: Google ngrams history?

Comment: @Mitch - for a neologism?

Comment: @user070221 I didn’t say it doesn’t exist. I was agreeing with Chris that a portmanteau of _dinner_ and _lunch_ should not logically have an r in the middle there, and its presence makes the word less obvious to those who’ve never heard it before.

Comment: @user070221 ?? If it's in a dictionary, then presumably the lexicographers found _some_ instances in the wild. Even so, basic research just to see if it was ever used before.

Comment: @Mitch - there is this 2013 article http://wjlondon.com/so-what-is-drunch/ - it is also used in French https://www.lemonde.fr/vous/article/2009/01/21/apres-le-brunch-l-heure-du-drunch_1144711_3238.html and Italian http://www.stile.it/2011/12/01/ci-vediamo-per-cena-no-per-un-drunch-4201-id-104455/

Comment: Skeptical/incredulous users might be more forgiving if you explained in your answer how you came across this term, and cited the source. And BTW I said "it appears to be business jargon" not that it is, I can see how a businessman might invite a client for a drink (at a pub, cocktail bar or wine bar) followed by lunch. If you did hear it used at Masterchef, or Hell's Kitchen you should say so.

Comment: Note that "brunch" is a well-established and well-known term (at least in the US).  I've never really heard "drunch" fired in anger, but one does on rare occasions hear "lupper", used in a somewhat jocular sense.

Comment: Because it is fairly new, it seems that 'drunch' doesn't have a consistent set meaning. Following all of the links given, English and other, it could be lunch with drinks, a late lunch, an early dinner, a buffet spread for dinner, mostly decided on by the commercial establishment that wants to encourage customers to have another excuse to spend money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Time Out*, London's famous guide to eating (and drinking) out; [Paris edition](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AlpS1eGMO28C&pg=PT496&dq=drunch&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk4rLj_cHdAhUX84MKHU7oDWMQ6AEIPDAD#v=onepage&q=drunch&f=false), **2012**

> ### Let's Do Drunch
>
> But now loafers can enjoy '**Le Drunch**', a lunch-dinner hybrid, which means that partied-out Parisians can head out for curative cuisine even later on Sundays.  Here are four surefire drunch joints to help dispel the Sunday afternoon blues

The [blend word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_word) appeared in **1975** in the linguistics journal, [*Poetica*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4TlJAAAAYAAJ&q=%22drunch%20for%20drinks%20plus%20lunch;%20and%20dinter%20for%20dinner%20before%20or%20after%20a%20professional%20interview%22&dq=%22drunch%20for%20drinks%20plus%20lunch;%20and%20dinter%20for%20dinner%20before%20or%20after%20a%20professional%20interview%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYg_-MgcLdAhVW1IMKHb0_CVcQ6AEIKjAA). [emphasis mine]

> Such are *brunch* for breakfast and lunch in one meal; **drunch** for **drinks plus lunch**; and *dinter* for dinner before or after a professional interview. In weather reports *foggle* means fog and drizzle; *smog*, smoke and fog;…
>
> Poetica: An International Journal of Linguistic‐Literary Studies, issues 3-6.

However, it appears that the term was later popularised in Paris

> Sunday mornings are for sleeping, Sunday afternoons should be for eating, misbehaving just a little bit more before going back to work and the healthy eating that comes with Monday – Friday life. Decisions, decisions…go out for dinner, go out for lunch, can’t decide? **The concept of Le Drunch was a food trend to emerge from Paris**. ([source](https://www.themarkerhoteldublin.com/eat-drink-experience/the-brasserie/le-drunch/))

On May 3 **2011**, in a Belgian blog called “[Life In Brussels](http://brusselian.blogspot.com/2011/05/drunch-pavillon-louis-xv.html)” the meaning of the term is explained.  The "fake" deletions are by the author.

> While brunch is often late in the morning / early afternoon, the brunch is designed for <del>even more</del> lazy people who do not leave home before tea time. This is indeed a <del>terrible</del> contraction of dinner and lunch, the drunch is therefore from 16 hours.
>   (Translation by Google)

From *[Le Figaro](http://www.lefigaro.fr/scope/articles-attitudes/2009/01/07/08011-20090107ARTFIG00650-le-drunch-le-before-du-dimanche-soir-.php)* January 14, **2009**

> Après le brunch, le « drunch ». Ou comment mixer lunch et dîner. Une tendance qui s'impose peu à peu dans les bars comme à la maison. le dimanche est en train d'émerger. Après le boom du brunch, voici le « drunch », un compromis entre lunch et d inner. On dit aussi « slunch » (souper et lunch réunis).

Google translation
*After the brunch, the "drunch". Or how to mix lunch and dinner. A trend that is needed gradually in bars and at home. 
A new way of receiving Sunday is emerging. After the brunch boom, here is the drunch, a compromise between lunch and dinner. We also say "slunch" (dinner and lunch together).*

### British Blend

From a thesis entitled *[Separating Blends](http://rdues.bcu.ac.uk/publ/Debbie_Danks_Thesis-Appendices.pdf)*, submitted to the University of Liverpool, dated September **2003**, the author Debbie Danks cites the following in the appendices

> In Potter **(1969)** p81:
>
> ***drunch*** - **drinks + lunch**
>   *dinter* - dinner + interview
>   *Joggle* -Jog + drizzle
>   *smaze* - smoke + haze

It therefore appears that *drunch* was originally the blending of *drinks* and *lunch*, hence justifying the presence of the letters *dr*, and dates back as far as 1969. Sometime in the late noughties (2000s), the term was ‘reinvented’ mimicking the already well-established expression ***brunch***, but its semantic meaning had broadened. Today *drunch* includes both definitions

1. **d**inner + l**unch**
2. **dr**inks + l**unch**

Comment: https://myrp.maruzen.co.jp/ibd/intl_9244/ this collection is dated between 1974- Spring 2016